# Как определяется высота над уровнем моря в этом Google Map приложение?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

Есть такой сервис
http://3planeta.com/googlemaps/karty-google-maps.html
как у них определяется высота над уровнем моря/ Есть такие же исходники?

Comment: [The Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте используется [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro)

Для работы нужно получить ключ API, после чего высоту над уровнем моря можно получать таким запросом:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=<широта>,<долгота>&key=<ключ API>
```

Результат:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 213.1804809570312,  //высота над уровнем моря
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 55.7498598,
            "lng" : 37.3523251
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Удобнее пользоваться сервисом [Elevation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation). [Пример от google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple).

Answer (score -1):

На сколько я помню, берется карта возвышенностей (переведенная в программный код), и смотрится по точке, которую вы указали. Грубо говоря, Московская возвышенность=>Какая высота?=>Выводит.